# C# set image url from a local server

Tags: c#

I am building an application, in which if the user didn't enter a photo during registration, a default photo will be displayed,

I have written this code to select the image.

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(@"Image/undefinedProfileImage.png");
```

However, Visual Studio told me that this image does not exist, even though I can see it in the `Image` folder.

I have tried searching the web and found that most people put an `@` before the image location.

[image]

Comment: the @ tells C# to treat the string as a literal.

Comment: could you please provide more information, is this MVC/Webforms/mobile app/etc.

Comment: @AshleyMedway it is mvc 4

Comment: Where is located the Image folder?

Comment: @SalvatoreSorbello it is `Images` in the root

Comment: @user2208349 by root you mean the project's root? or the drive's root?

Comment: @SalvatoreSorbello the project root

Comment: @user2208349 so if you are trying do debug the project form visual studio (compiled in debug) inside the debug folder you have correctly the Image folder with the png inside, right?

Comment: @SalvatoreSorbello yes i have it in the `Image` folder, in the root of the project,

Comment: if your project's root folder is for example MyProject (where is located the .sln file) and you are debugging from visual studio, the image should be inside MyProject\bin\Debug\Image\ you can confirm this?

Comment: From the pictures you added,go inside the image folder and check the image's property, there is the property copy in the output directory, you should tell him ,yes copy and in the compilation operation "nothing" check maybe is embedded as resource

Comment: it was `dont copy`, i change it to `copy always` but still have this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Should provide `tilde (~)` operator to specify that `Image` folder in your Current project folder and also use `Server.MapPath()`

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/Image/undefinedProfileImage.png"));
```

and your `Image` Folder Should be in your Root Folder as Below:

```
MyProject/Image/
```

Note : @ symbol is used to specify the Path intact as it is.

**Example:**

`String path="Project\\Image\\imagefile.jpg"`
is same as using `@`

`String path=@"Project\Image\imagefile.jpg"`

Server.MapPath("~/Images/Image.jpg")

Comment: it told me that image not found,  although it is therre

Comment: try with this Image img = Image.FromFile("~/Image/undefinedProfileImage.png"); you dont need @ symbol

Comment: this is the exception `/Images/undefinedProfileImage.png

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: ~/Images/undefinedProfileImage.png

Source Error`

Comment: is your folder name Image or Images i'm confused becoz you mentioned in question as Image.

Comment: it is `Images`, it was just a typo in my question, sorry, please help

Comment: where is your file either.aspx ot html ., imean source file from where you are running this?

Comment: it is mvc 4, i run it in a controller in the controllers folder

Comment: check my edited answer , you need to use Server.MapPath , it works Perfectly

Comment: you help a lot and i appreciate ur help

Comment: It's my pleasure to Help you, Have a Nice Day :)

Comment: kindly help me please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001729/how-to-get-the-image-and-id-from-my-simplemembership