# how to get the image and ID from my simplemembership

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4

i am using this table for simpemembership

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
    public class UserProfile
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    }
```

It works perfect, i made my configration and migration and creating users and accounts and login and everything is perfect,

now a user login to my system , i make this

```
WebSecurity.Login(username, encryptedPassword, false);
```

it works.

i want to use the users informatoin in my views.

For example, i make this `Request.isAuthenticated` to know if the user is authenticated or not. but also i want to use his ID and IMage **(remeber that table has these informatoin)**

how can i use them please?7

#### edit

in other worlds:

i want to use `User.Identity.` but i can just see the `name`,, i can't see the id and the image

#### edit 2

at the top of my mind, i think that if this is not possible, is it a good think to store the image and id in the cookie?thank u

Comment: Is the image and name being used in a view or is it on the `_layout` shared view?

Comment: Avoid putting lots of code in your view. You could do something similar to what Kevin suggests below, but if you need access to the information on `_layout` where you cannot use a model, then use Javascript/JQuery to call into the controller and return the info async. Similar to this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868817/model-for-layout-cshtml-on-mvc4/17882226#17882226

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [article on customizing SimpleMembership](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/01/seeding-customizing-aspnet-mvc.html). It shows how to get the *UserProfile* object for the current user.  Here is an example that shows how to grab the *UserProfile* object and access an email property that was added.

```
var context = new UsersContext();
var username = User.Identity.Name;
var user = context.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
var email = user.Email;
```

Another alternative is to use the [open source project SimpleSecurity](https://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/), which decouples SimpleMembership from your ASP.NET application and extends functionality such as email confirmation and password reset.  There is a class that extends the *WebSecurity* class and has a method *WebSecurity.GetUser* that takes the username as a parameter and returns the *UserProfile* associated with it.

Comment: is it good to play with the websecurity already defined code? also for the first solutoin, i can use that in my view like i can for the name `user.identity.Name` but your solution is to use in controllers and i am asking about the view

Comment: Nothing wrong with extending WebSecurity since it is missing some critical methods required for the anything other than the simplest (pun intended) application, such as getting the UserProfile for the current user. You could write an HTML helper that uses the same code if you want it in the view. But I think the better solution is to keep it in the Controller and pass it to the View in your Model, hence MVC.